# Extracting shared memory's size

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, shared-memory

I'm trying to understand how exactly i should extract MapViewOfFile's return buffer size. I used the following command to allocate a shared memory

```
hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nullptr, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, dwDataSize, strSharedMemoryName.c_str());
```

Filled it with stuff using the following code snippet:

```
pBuffer = DynamicAPI::MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, dwDataSize);
if (nullptr == pBuffer || GetLastError() != 0)
{
    LOG_ERROR(L"Failed to MapViewOfFile: " << GetLastError());
    break;
}
// Copy buffer to the shared memory
::CopyMemory(pBuffer, pData, dwDataSize);
```

And then, somewhere else, tried to reopen that shared memory and read the overall buffer:

```
HANDLE hSharedMemory = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, FALSE, m_strSharedName.c_str());
    if (nullptr == hSharedMemory)
    {
        return false;
    }

    LPVOID pData = nullptr;
    if (nullptr == (pData = MapViewOfFile(hSharedMemory, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0)))
    {
        LOG_ERROR(L"Failed to MapViewOfFile");
        return false;
    }
```

my next line was going to be

```
std::string strData = pData; // use std::string::assign
```

However, i have no idea how big `pData` is, one option is to send the overall size in the buffer, however MSDN states that `VirtualQueryEx` is capable of doing such thing.

I tried to execute the following code snippet:

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;
SIZE_T szBufferSize = ::VirtualQueryEx(::GetCurrentProcess(), pData, &info, sizeof(info));
```

But this, gives me the size of a single page if I'm not mistaken, how do i utilize this to give me the size of the overall buffer?

thanks!

Comment: `But this, gives me the size of a single page if I'm not mistaken` Depends on what the meaning of "this" is. `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION::RegionSize` should give you - wait for it - the size of the region. If you instead are looking at the return value of `VirtualQueryEx`, then that's just basically `sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)` (as described in the documentation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to retrieve the size of an existing file mapping or file mapping view.  You are expected to track this information yourself.

> MSDN states that VirtualQueryEx is capable of doing such thing.

No, all VirtualQueryEx can determine is the number of pages reserved for the view.  That means that the result is always rounded up to a page size.  Also, there is no explicit guarantee that MapViewOfFile will reserve only the minimum number of pages necessary to map the file.  For example, it might choose to round it up to the allocation granularity.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible, but Microsoft for some reason did not document it. The `NtQuerySection` API existed since early versions of Windows NT and still does in Windows 10.

So here's how you do it (obviously at your own risk of relying on an undocumented kernel API):

```
HANDLE hFileMapping = ::OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, FALSE, strSharedMemName);
_ASSERT(hFileMapping);

ULONGLONG uicbSharedMemSize = 0;

//Get the handle returned by the CreateFileMapping function
//Assuming the same process here...
HANDLE hDupH;
if((::DuplicateHandle(
    ::GetCurrentProcess(), hFileMapping, 
    ::GetCurrentProcess(), &hDupH,
    DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE | DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS, FALSE, 0)))
{
    hFileMapping = hDupH;

    enum SECTION_INFORMATION_CLASS{
        SectionBasicInformation,
        SectionImageInformation
    };

    typedef struct _SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION {
      ULONG                   Unknown;
      ULONG                   SectionAttributes;
      LARGE_INTEGER           SectionSize;
    } SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PSECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION;

    static NTSTATUS
    (NTAPI
    *pfnNtQuerySection)(
      IN HANDLE               SectionHandle,
      IN SECTION_INFORMATION_CLASS InformationClass,
      OUT PVOID               InformationBuffer,
      IN ULONG                InformationBufferSize,
      OUT PULONG              ResultLength OPTIONAL ) = NULL;

    if(!pfnNtQuerySection)
        (FARPROC&)pfnNtQuerySection = ::GetProcAddress(::GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtQuerySection");

    if(pfnNtQuerySection)
    {
        SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION sbi = {0};
        ULONG ucbRead = 0;
        NTSTATUS stat = pfnNtQuerySection(hFileMapping, SectionBasicInformation, &sbi, sizeof(sbi), &ucbRead);
        if(stat >= 0)
        {
            //The size returned will be rounded up to the page size (i.e. 4K in most cases)
            uicbSharedMemSize = sbi.SectionSize.QuadPart;
        }
    }
}
```

---

first of all correct definition for `SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION` is :

```
typedef struct _SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION
{
    PVOID BaseAddress;
    ULONG AllocationAttributes;
    LARGE_INTEGER MaximumSize;
} SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PSECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION;
```

so old definition (with `DWORD` first member - was wrong and will be not work for 64bit code).

at second for call `NtQuerySection` the section handle must have `SECTION_QUERY` access, otherwise will be `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` - so line:

```
OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, FALSE, strSharedMemName);
```

is wrong. must be

```
OpenFileMapping(SECTION_QUERY|FILE_MAP_READ|FILE_MAP_WRITE, FALSE, strSharedMemName);
```

or any access, including `SECTION_QUERY`

*note, that if use `OpenFileMapping` and set `dwDesiredAccess` exactly to `SECTION_QUERY` the `OpenFileMapping` by unknown reason change it to `SECTION_MAP_READ` - was next line of code inside this api. `if (dwDesiredAccess == SECTION_QUERY) dwDesiredAccess = SECTION_MAP_READ;`
so need add some access to `SECTION_QUERY`. of course we can use `SECTION_QUERY` exactly with [`ZwOpenSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567029(v=vs.85).aspx)*

next - for what call `DuplicateHandle` ?!? this is absolute senseless in task context call. we got handle to section via `OpenFileMappingW` or `ZwOpenSection`.

and finally for what `GetModuleHandle` + `GetProcAddress` for `ZwQuerySection` ? how we interesting call `OpenFileMappingW` without `GetModuleHandle` + `GetProcAddress` for example ? how `GetProcAddress` call ? in same way we can call `ZwQuerySection` - simply link with *ntdll.dll* via *ntdll.lib* which exist in every *wdk* lib folder. so final code must be:

```
if (HANDLE hMap = OpenFileMappingW(SECTION_QUERY|SECTION_MAP_READ, FALSE, name))
{
    SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION sbi;
    if (0 <= ZwQuerySection(hMap, SectionBasicInformation, &sbi, sizeof(sbi), 0))
    {
        DbgPrint("section size = %I64x\n", sbi.Size.QuadPart);
    }
    CloseHandle(hMap);
}
```

or

```
HANDLE hMap;
if (0 <= ZwOpenSection(&hMap, SECTION_QUERY, &oa))
{
    SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION sbi;
    if (0 <= ZwQuerySection(hMap, SectionBasicInformation, &sbi, sizeof(sbi), 0))
    {
        DbgPrint("section size = %I64x\n", sbi.Size.QuadPart);
    }
    CloseHandle(hMap);
}
```

Comment: for what you call `DuplicateHandle` ?

Comment: also your definition of `SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION` is wrong. must be http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntmmapi_8h_source.html#l00178. as result you got wrong result on 64bit

Comment: @RbMm: OK, you're right, the `SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION` was wrong for x64. I also missed the `SECTION_QUERY` and thus resorted to calling `DuplicateHandle` to make it work. As for statically linking to `ntdll.dll` that may also be a shorter version of the code.

Comment: `DuplicateHandle` can "help" only if another handle, which we duplicate with `DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS` already have `SECTION_QUERY` otherwise nothing change. really need just open section with correct access (`SECTION_QUERY`)